# virtualenv path not changed in Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to use Python virtualenv and not sure how to change the PATH file,

This is what I did,

1. Created a Virtualenv
2. Execute path\to\env\scripts\activate within the environment

Now, I'm trying to check my PATH variable but nothing has changed, still pointing to the same old environment

Is my understanding correct that the path will be changed by my 2) command.

Comment: Where do you want to use virtualenv? In command line?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this point:

> Execute path\to\env\scripts\activate within the environment

Did you do it by executing the following:

```
source path\to\env\scripts\activate
```

?

Doing that should change PATH and prompt temporarily (until you execute `deactivate`).

Comment: I just did - path\to\env\scripts\activate and not - source path\to\env\scripts\activate..

Comment: @user1050619: So try this command, as suggested in my answer. Running script will not have the effect you would expect, but `source filename` does. What is the result?